# Вывод данных из бд с сортировкой

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Есть таблица `db_weapons`.

[image: db_weapons]

Как составить подзапросы mysql для вывода из таблицы всех значений, но при этом сортируя их по категориям которые записаны в ячейке `quality`

Что бы выведенный вид был таков:

```
----------------------------
id: 3, quality: 'base_grade',
id: 5, quality: 'base_grade',
id: 4, quality: 'exotic',
id: 6, quality: 'exotic',
id: 2, quality: 'restricted',
id: 7, quality: 'restricted',
id: 1, quality: 'covert'
----------------------------
```

Это всё для того что бы не сортировать силами php
Но есть  кто-то знает решение на php которое займёт мало времени на обработку, то я буду рад принять помощь и рассмотреть пример.

Comment: Чем обычный `Order by quality` не устраивает?

Comment: Какая то у вас странная сортировка, сначала слова на 'b', потом e,r и внезапно 'c'. Если по алфавиту - то ответ вам написали - используйте select * from table order by quality

Comment: Тем что оно выведет всё строго по алфавиту [A-Z | Z-A] А мне нужно выводить в очередности как мне хочется, к примеру     `['exotic','base_grade','restricted','covert']`

Comment: @Mike, Почему **странная**, я не писал, что по алфавиту. Мне нужно произвольно, но по группам.

Comment: А если бы вы сортировали их на php в ручном режиме, чем бы вы руководствовались для определения положения той или иной группы ?

Comment: Странная конечно сортировка,но в таком случае создайте дополнительное поле которое будет хранить порядковый номер для сортировки,и по нему сортируйте как вам хочется!

Comment: @Mike, Сделал бы функцию с циклом в котором стояло бы определенное количество if (зависит от количества групп) и заносило бы каждую группу в свой массив, потом бы соединил эти массивы в один и вывел через цикл

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM db_weapons 
WHERE quality IN ('base_grade','exotic','restricted','covert') 
ORDER BY FIELD(quality, 'base_grade','exotic','restricted','covert')
```

Comment: Еще вариант quality сделать enum 
`ALTER TABLE db_weapons
MODIFY COLUMN quality  enum('base_grade','exotic','restricted','covert');`

Answer (score 4):

Вам надо создать справочник групп, примерно такой:

```
ord  quality
1    exotic
2    base_grade
3    restricted
4    covert
```

И запрос выборки из основной таблице сделать тогда таким:

```
select A.*
  from db_weapons A, qualityOrd B
 where B.quality=A.quality
 order by B.ord
```

В любом случае SQL надо явно сказать в каком порядке должна быть сортировка, волшебного оператора "отсортируй как мне хочется" к сожалению не предусмотрено.

Но по хорошему, даже при отсутствии необходимости особой сортировки такой справочник нужен. Не стоит хранить в основной таблице повторяющиеся текстовые значения. При вводе текста человек может ошибиться буквой и это будет уже другая группа. И если захочется переименовать группу или придать группе еще и русское название - ему придется делать это во всех записях. Обычно в подобных ситуациях названия хранятся в справочнике, а в основной таблице только ID группы.

Comment: Понял, на счет замечаний спасибо, но редактирование не предусмотрено, названия групп статические и никогда меняться не будут.

Comment: Тогда вам не нужна отдельная таблица. Зачем вам лишний JOIN в запросе, когда можно обойтись скалярным выражением?

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан никогда не говори никогда :) все когда нибудь меняется и в базу добавить одну запись с новой группой на порядок проще, чем лазить по всему коду, править запросы, менять if в программе в куче мест ... И хранение порядка сортировки в базе удобнее по тем же причинам - если решили поменять - взяли и поменяли, а не сидим и не вспоминаем в скольких запросах мы эту сортировку жестко зашили

Comment: @Mike, я с тобой согласен, но в данном случаи думаю можно обойтись так, я задам еще одну ячейку с приоритетом(приоритет можно менять в админке) , и буду выводить по этому приоритету, что бы можно было выводить и по группам в любом порядке и даже взять одну запись с группы, к примеру, той что в конце и поставить её в начало перед всеми или после 2-й группы...

Answer (score 3):

Например ORDER BY + CASE

```
SELECT *
FROM db_weapons
ORDER BY 
  CASE quality
    WHEN quality = 'base_grade' THEN 1
    WHEN quality = 'exotic'     THEN 2
    WHEN quality = 'restricted' THEN 3
    WHEN quality = 'covert'     THEN 4
    ELSE 99 --неизвестные в конце
  END
```

Answer (score -1):

Покапай в сторону GROUP BY, а потом уже будешь вытаскивать группы по очередности которые нужны.

Comment: group точно ничего не даст. потому как записи нужны все. а оконных функций в mysql нет